# Use sed to replace a string within a range using a multi-line text range

Tags: sed, macos

I have the following in a file (values.yaml):

```
global:
  repo1:
    enabled: true
  repo2:
    enabled: true

repo1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always

repo2:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: latest
    pullPolicy: Always
```

and I want to replace the `tag: latest` for repo1 with something like `tag: newest1` and `tag: latest` for repo2 with something like `tag: newest2` so that I end up with:

```
global:
  repo1:
    enabled: true
  repo2:
    enabled: true

repo1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: newest1
    pullPolicy: Always

repo2:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: newest2
    pullPolicy: Always
```

So I'm trying to search a range from `repo1:\n  replicaCount:1` to either `pullPolicy` or the end of the file so I get a range that has just the one tag in it and can replace it.

I have

```
sed -i "" "N;/repo1:\n  replicaCount:/,/pullPolicy/s/tag:.*/tag: newest1/g" values.yaml
```

and that *almost* works, but it always deletes the very last `pullPolicy` line like:

```
global:
  repo1:
    enabled: true
  repo2:
    enabled: true

repo1:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: newest1
    pullPolicy: Always

repo2:
  replicaCount: 1
  image:
    tag: newest2
```

And I'm on a Mac, which is why all the double quotes.

How do I specify the end range to either be the end of the file (I've also tried `$` to no avail) or to be the pullPolicy?

Comment: `sed` would be a poor choice of tool for doing this. See https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/ for how to install/use a yaml editor and if you can't install `yq` for some reason then you'd use `awk`.

Comment: Change the `N` in your sed code to `$!N`. The lonely N is causing the last line to not be printed. Take care to backslash it since you are inside double quotes. For a robust way lookat my solution using python.  I like your approach of combining N with range.

Answer (score 1):

`sed -z` uses null character separator instead of newlines.

```
cat values.yaml | sed -z "s/\nrepo\([0-9]*\):\n\(\([^\n]\+\n\)*\)\([ \t]*\)tag:[^\n]*/\nrepo\1:\n\2\4tag: new\1/g"
```

does what you want.

- `\nrepo\([0-9]*\):\n` matches with a line starting with `repo`, and records its value in `\1`.
- `\(\([^\n]\+\n\)*\)` matches with any number of non-empty lines (`\+` is for at least one char), and records its value in `\2`. `\3` is wasted for the inside group.
- `\([ \t]*\)tag:[^\n]*` matches with a line containing the word `tag` with space indent.
- `\nrepo\1:\n\2\4` lets the first lines unchanged.
- `tag: new\1` changes the tag value, with `new` + the repo value.
- `/g` is used to do both changes with a single command.

If it does not work, you can try with `gnu-sed` (can be installed on MacOS too) instead of your default `sed`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -ri ':1;/^repo[12]/,/tag/!b;/tag/!{N;b1};s/^(repo(.).*)latest$/\1newest\2/'
```

Do not forget about the **l** command for debugging, which shows what you have in the current buffer. e.g:

```
sed -nr ':1;/^repo[12]/,/tag/!b;/tag/!{N;b1};l;s/^(repo(.).*)latest$/\1newest\2/' file

repo1:\n  replicaCount: 1\n  image:\n    tag: latest$
repo2:\n  replicaCount: 1\n  image:\n    tag: latest$
```

Production:

```
sed -ri '/^repo[12]/!b;:1;/tag/!{N;b1};s/^(repo(.).*)latest$/\1newest\2/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `python` the way to edit this file is to import the yaml module then load the yaml file in a python dictionary, aka, hash | associative array, albeit a nested one.

Then we go in n tweak the  values of the keys in the yaml file.

Finally we save the dictionary back into the yaml file.

The sed code is to insert empty lines on the top level nodes if yaml file.

```
$ yaml_file='values.yaml'

$ python3 - "$yaml_file" <<\YAML
import sys, yaml

yaml_doc = sys.argv[1]

with open(yaml_doc) as fp:
  h = yaml.safe_load(fp)

h['repo1']['image']['tag'] = 'newest1'
h['repo2']['image']['tag'] = 'newest2'

with open(yaml_doc, 'w') as fp:
  yaml.safe_dump(h, fp, default_flow_style=False)
YAML

$ sed -Ei -e '1!{/^\S/{H;z;x;};}' "$yaml_file"
```